# Python shebang execution permission denied

Tags: python, executable, permission-denied, shebang

I have a very simple script called `blah.py` which looks like this:

```
#!/space/jazz/1/users/gwarner/anaconda/bin python
print 'here'
```

My `which python` returns `/space/jazz/1/users/gwarner/anaconda/bin/python` and `ls -l blah.py` returns `-rwxrwxr-x 1 gwarner gwarner 64 Jul 13 14:16 blah.py`. My username is `gwarner`. However, when I try to execute this script from the directory it lives in using `./blah.py` I get `./blah.py: Permission denied`. It runs correctly when I execute it using `python blah.py`. What is going on?

Comment: `chmod +x blah.py`, you need to give it an executable bit.

Comment: Did you miss a space between `/bin` and `python` in the shebang?

Comment: @NightShadeQueen it already has executable permission, see the `ls -l` in the original post.

@ChrisSprague no, I didn't miss a space.

Comment: @GWarner my bad, is there an extra space in there is what I meant

Comment: @GWarner, @ChrisSprague is saying you have a space between `bin` and `python` in the `#!` line and it should be a `/` instead. You are trying to run this script with `bin` as the execution program. That's not going to work because `bin` is a directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have an extra space in the shebang line... try this:

```
#!/space/jazz/1/users/gwarner/anaconda/bin/python
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `/space/jazz/1/users/gwarner/anaconda/bin` file does indeed have executable permissions set.

Answer (score -2):

You are trying to run `blah.py` as an executable file. For that you might need to run this on the terminal

```
sudo chmod +x blah.py
```

to change the permission of the file and make it executable.

Comment: OP said the file's permissions are reported as `-rwxrwxr-x`, so isn't it already executable?

Comment: If I am correct the highest permission level is `-rwxrwxrwx` at 777. So, maybe the change is required. @GWarner did you try doing it?

Comment: @o11c I've clearly stated about the permission changes. How can you coin the term 'careless'?

Comment: @HimanshuMishra 777 is the most permissive, but this user owns the script file, making it globally permissive is unnecessary and possibly dangerous, as it allows any other user to read and even modify the file.

Comment: @HimanshuMishra you should NEVER EVER use `sudo` unless you know exactly what privilege you lack without it and why you can't find another way. It is NOT some magical "fix all errors" command. `sudo` is EXTREMELY dangerous; using it in this case where it is obviously unneeded is a REALLY bad habit.